# Prove that $S+T$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nilpotence, invariant-subspace

> Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space and let $S$ and $T$ be two linear operators of $V$. If $S$ and $T$ are both nilpotent and $ST=TS$ then $S+T$ and $ST$ are nilpotent operators

I got this:
By hypothesis, $S$ and $T$ are nilpotent operators, which implies that $T^k=0$ and $S^q=0$ for some $k,q \in N$
Then $S^q+T^k=0+0=0$

Therefore $S+T$ is nilpotent, but I am not so sure if my argument is enough to prove what it is required.

Comment: You need a power of $(S+T)$ to be zero. Try $(S+T)^{q+k}$..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To show $ST$ is nilpotent, it helps to note that $ST=TS$ means $(ST)^n=S^nT^n$

Comment: How can I be sure that S^q+T^k=(S+T)^q+k

Comment: They are equal, but this is not the way to proceed. The way is by using the binomial theorem, which would apply for commuting matrices.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider $(S+T)^{q+k}$. Make sure to use that $ST=TS$.

Comment: Why do I have to be sure that ST=TS, what does that mean?

Comment: @IvanBravo:  when you expand the binomial, you should use $ST=TS$ to simplify